# How to replace %20 with -

Tags: php, wordpress, replace

How to replace %20 with -. 
(Wordpress)

So what i need: link like `://www.yyy.xx/tag/55 5/`

should change in `://www.yyy.xx/tag/55-5/`

instead of: `http://www.yyy.xx/tag/55%205/`

Comment: Tried [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)?

Comment: this doesn't appear to be a wordpress question - unless you are asking about permalinks?

Answer (score 0):

Try using str_replace for that.

like for example.

```
$url = "http://www.yyy.xx/tag/55%205/";
$url = str_replace('%20', '-', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.
That filter changes your URL.
I wrote it here so I don't test it if doesn't work try to experiment to fetch tag.

```
    function custom_link($link, $term, $taxonomy) {
       if ( is_tag() ) {
         return $link;
       }
       return str_replace('%20', '-', $link);
    }
    add_filter('tag_link', 'custom_link', 10, 3);
```

or

```
    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    function custom_link() {
      if (strpos($url,'%20') == true) {
        return str_replace('%20', '-', $url);
      } 
    add_filter('tag_link', 'custom_link', 10, 3);
```

Comment: There is also another option. If you make a tag for example 'white fish', link to post with 'white fish' wil be example.com/tag/white-fish

Comment: How to change that in example.com/white%20fish, thanks for helping me out:)

Comment: First of all try in Settings->Pemalinks
1.Set Custom Structure: /%postname%/
2.Set Category and Tag  base: . (dot not /)
3.Save.